# how to parse JSON like this

Tags: android

```
[
    {
        "0": "1",
        "1": "ANIMALS",
        "2": "7a415-lion.png",
        "id": "1",
        "category_name": "ANIMALS",
        "category_image": "http://dev1.sbsgroupsolutions.co.in/emoticonapp/admin/assets/uploads/7a415-lion.png"                               
    }


]
```

Comment: What did you tried ? There is tons of examples show us some code...

Comment: @Abhi Satle It's simple, with gson you can convert a JSON object to java object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if something is returning you this json array then store it in a jsonarray object :-

```
JSONArray array;
```

Then instantiate a JSONObject :-

```
JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject();
```

give the necessary index.

and then use getString to get the values . Eg.

```
String s1 = object.getString("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use GSON, library for reading and creating JSON for Java

Comment: will you please give me some more details for this,

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonresponse);
JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
String categoryname=jsonObj.getString(category_name);
```

Comment: It's better if you explain *why* your code solves the problem. See [answer].